# Collections.sort no compile time error

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparable

What is the difference between `Collections.sort(list)` and `Collections.sort(list,null)`
I supposed both of them compared elements in the list in their natural order.

So I tried these two codes:

**CODE 1:**

```
List<Object> list=Arrays.asList("hello",123);
Collections.sort(list);
```

**CODE 2:**

```
List<Object> list=Arrays.asList("hello",123);
Collections.sort(list,null);
```

The latter compiles but former doesn't giving the expected compiler error that instances of class Object are not comparable.
Why latter does not give compile time error.

**EDIT:** Based on the comment given below. I understand why latter doesn't give compile time error but on running it throws `ClassCastException : String cannot be converted into Integer` . How it deduced that runtime objects are String and Integer because what I think

```
public static sort(List<Object> list)  ---> Since list was of type object
{
// For instances of object in list call the compareTo method 
}
```

}

Comment: `null` is a valid comparator. Try running it though...

Comment: On running it gives ClassCastException  --  java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different methods in `Collections`

```
//here the elements in list should impl. Comparable
Collections.sort(list) 
//here we need a Comparator object, (null is Comparator obj too)
Collections.sort(list, null)
```

Now comes to the question of runtime classcast problem.

Java converts your list into array to do the sort in background. If your `Comparator` is null, java will cast the element to `Comparable` to do sort. Fortunately, the two elements in your list both (`String and Integer`) implemented `Comparable`. so till here no Exception.

You have only two elements (2<7 7 is the insertionsort threshold) in your list, so java just simply do insertion sort. Take the Integer, and call the `compareTo()` method with your string as parameter. Here java cast the parameter to Integer, so that it can compare. As you've seen, `String` cannot be cast to `Integer`, you got that Exception.

Comment: Your answer is quite satisfactory . Just a doubt about this line java will cast the element to Comparable to do sort. Does it uses getClass method to determine these elements at runtime

Comment: No, if you check the codes, java simply does `((Comparable) dest[j-1]).compareTo(dest[j])>0; j--)` to convert your elements into `Comparable`. and your classcastEx was not occurred here.  @user2653926

Answer (score 2):

Java's generic types are checked at compile time. If you violate the constraits, you can't even  compile. The first method is defined as:

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

That requires that the `List` you use is of a type that `extend Comparable`, specifically some `Comparable<X>` where X may be any superclass of T. Sounds complicated but doesn't even matter here (try understanding http://yzaslavs.blogspot.de/2010/07/generics-pecs-principle-step-by-step.html if you're interested in that part). `List<Object>` does not match the first part already. `Object` doesn't implement any `Comparable`. => Compiler says no.

The second one is defined as

```
<T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

that no longer requires that the type of the `List` has any special property. Any T will work. The only requirement is that you can provide an implementation of `Comparator` that is able to sort T or a super type. `null` is like a joker and fits *anything*. The compiler will not complain even if using null is probably wrong. You do see the problem at runtime.

---

The reason for

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Integer.java:52)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:290)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:157)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:537)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:178)
    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

is that at "TimSort.java:178" it does

```
static <T> void  sort(T[] a, int lo, int hi, Comparator<? super T> c) {
    if (c == null) {
        Arrays.sort(a, lo, hi);
        return;
    }
```

which falls back to natural sorting like your first call would do. However it's just a `Object[]` array at that point and nothing can guarantee that types are actually comparable. It simply casts the types and that fails depending on your luck & content of the list either in Integer.compareTo( ) or String.compareTo( ) because those methods require their own type.

Answer (score 0):

```
> what is null?
```

According to JSL -

> There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null,
>   which has no name. Because the null type has no name, it is impossible
>   to declare a variable of the null type or to cast to the null type.
>   The null reference is the only possible value of an expression of null
>   type. The null reference can always be cast to any reference type. In
>   practice, the programmer can ignore the null type and just pretend
>   that null is merely a special literal that can be of any reference
>   type.

As `null` can be reference of any type so it can be reference of `Comparator` as well, That is why compiler accepts `Collections.sort(list,null);`.

Where as `Collections.sort(list,new Object());` gives compile time exception.

---

At the time of comparison check `compareTo` Method will be called Where in `Integer.compareTo` method it generate `ClassCastException`.

Comment: If list had Object type of Elements then how Integer.compareTo was called

Comment: Internally call `margeSort` to sort elements, [find it here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.mergeSort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between these two, Is clearly mentioned in api doc.
Refer [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)